# gnome3 add new file types for nautilus (instead of text file)

Tags: linux, fedora, gnome3, nautilus, file-types

on my Fedora 20 system many file types are grouped under the type "text", for example *.ini, *.txt and so on.

So if I sort the contents of a folder by type, it groups them all together, which is not at all helping me.

Even after a longer frustrating search, I still can't figure out how to create a new filetype based on the extension (say *.ini) to show up in nautilus as "parameter file".

It would really help my workflow to resolve that.

Can somebody help?

Comment: You can't. You can only group by "basic types" (this is hardcoded in `nautilus`) or by mimetype if you enable that column, see my answer [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/177954)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you would do.
In Gnome, filetypes are determined by a little tool called "file".
You pass "file" a file and it tells you the file's so called "mimetype", sometimes also named "content-type".

You can read about mimetype/content-type here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME

About the usage of the utility "file":
http://linux.die.net/man/1/file

As far as I am concerned, these filetype labels are standardized/fixed and cannot be "overwritten" by users.
Meaning, if I am right, you cannot create your "own" filetype "Banana" for any, say, *.html files, just because you wanna have it displayed that way.

Getting your "own" filetype displayed is one thing, the other thing is opening a file of a specific filetype with the correct program is another, but you haven't mentioned that would be a problem for you, or is it?

Have fun.

Comment: ok thank you for your reply! looks like this is more complicated than I thought, so maybe I just arrange myself with it. could well be the first thing I miss since windows days